# Points where this three varible function takes the value $1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

I need to find minima of this function. 
$f(a,b,c)=2^a-5^b\cdot7^c$    where $a,b,c$ are positive integer

I need to prove that for any value of a,b,c the value of function can never be 1. Tried plotting graph but coudn't find anything interesting.

Comment: It is sometimes negative, so the question may need modification.

Comment: edited it. A solution reached through graph will be of great help

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $2^a-5^b7^c=1$ for some $a,b,c$. Then, since $b,c\ge1$:
$$2^a\equiv1\pmod {35}$$

Trying out powers of two mod $35$ (the little Fermat's theorem can shorten the work) we can see that $a$ must be a multiple of $12$. That is,
$$a=12d$$

But $2^{12d}-1$ is a multiple of $2+1$, that is, $3$, so it has other factors than $5$ and $7$. So indeed, there's no solution.

**Note:** if you allow $b$ or $c$ be $0$, there are no solutions either. For $b=1$, $c=0$ and for $b=0$, $c=1$, it can be easily checked, and [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_conjecture) (already proved) covers all other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Would you mind giving me a solution using graphs as I need to explain it to someone in 8th grade.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this can be proven with a graph. This is algebra... In fact, if you allow real exponents there are infinitely many solutions.